# Form a wrapped set of elements with a certain style value

Tags: jquery

I have a page of code I want to rip through and change the background-color on all .box divs that have an opacity < 1 to transparent, but I'm not seeing an elegant way to do  it.

There doesn't seem to be a style selector like there is an attribute selector:

```
                            $(‘element[attribute<value’])
```

I can do something like

```
       if($('.box').css('opacity') < 1) {
```

but then I need a 'this' to refer to the element that just passed the opacity < 1 test.

It seems like there should be an elegant way to do this in jQuery, but I'm not seeing it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: _"all #box divs"_ There should only be one div with the ID "box". IDs must be unique.

Comment: Is "box" the class name?

Comment: You could try `$('.box').css('background-color', function () {
    if ($(this).css('opacity') < 1) {
        return 'blue';
    }
});` Turn your ids to classes http://jsfiddle.net/936uC/ If you still want to work with dup ids then `$('[id="box"]')`

Comment: No, I don't want duplicate ids.  I should have used class.  I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function of jQuery to look on every matched element

an example from the documentation:

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

---

So you could do as following:

```
$( ".box" ).each(function( index ) {
  if( $(this).css('opacity') < 1 )
    // do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: These are all great solutions!  Thanks!  I chose this one because I use each() all the time so I'm familiar with it.  I should have seen this myself as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function:

```
var boxes = $(".box").filter(function(){
   return $(this).css("opacity") != 1;
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/UQ4gy/

Comment: he said "I can do something like" i think it just a typo.. and you are not answering the question..

Answer (score 1):

Use `.filter()` to reduce your jQuery object to the elements matching your desired condition:

```
$('.box').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('opacity')<1;
}).someMethod();
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution may be to use a **filter**...

```
$('.box').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('opacity') < 1;
}).css("opacity", 0);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hMmN6/

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

But you can also use a loop as others have suggested ...OR if you can already identify these non-opaque boxes, you can give them a class or a data attribute.

Here's an example which contains **4 different solutions**: http://jsfiddle.net/hMmN6/2/
Someone should see which is fastest.